# Geometrical description of cantor set is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Why is Cantor set uncountable?

I would like to intuitively understand the uncountable nature of Cantor set. When I construct Cantor set I do not feel so.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64354/uncountability-of-the-cantor-set?rq=1

Comment: I must say that many (though possibly not all) of the "theoretical" proofs you seem to disdain contain a nugget of intuition, where we have stripped off all the unnecessary assumptions and bared the basic principles causing the phenomenon (e.g. why perfect sets are uncountable/countable sets have isolated points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $T$ of ternary numbers:
$$
0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots
$$
where for all $i$, $a_i = 0$ or $a_i = 2$  will include numbers from the Cantor Set. 
(Does it include all of them?).

This means, that there is a one-to-one, inclusive map from the Cantor Set to the set described above.
(In fact it is **bijective, inclusive**, $T$=The Cantor Set) 
Assume that this is not true, and that there is a real number written in ternary with one of its digits as $1$, that is in the cantor set.
Assume, that its $n^{th}$ digit $a_n$ is $1$. 
Realize, that the set of real numbers with their $n^{th}$ digit as $1$, written in a unique ternary expansion, is the removed middle third of an interval during the Cantor Set Construction. 
Furthermore, label the cantor set as $\mathfrak{C}$ and assume that $\mathfrak{C}$ is a countable set. We have:
$$
\mathfrak{C} + \mathfrak{C} = [0,2]
$$
That is:
$$
\{x+y: x,y\in \mathfrak{C}\} = [0,2]
$$
Can you convince yourself of the above fact?
We have that $\mathfrak{C} + \mathfrak{C}$ surjects onto $\mathfrak{C}\times \mathfrak{C}$, which is the cartesian product of countable sets. This is a countable set. But, if you accept that $[0,2]$ is uncountable, we arrive at a contradiction. 
So, if you convince yourself of the above fact(s), then you should be happy at this point.

Comment: ($[0,2]$, rather.)

Comment: thanx sir@Rustyn,it was of great help.

Comment: aren't the digits either 0 or 2?

Comment: @MatthewLevy Ah! yes, you are right. Sorry to mislead! Edited